# Проблемы с Wildfly quickstart

Tags: java, wildfly

Скачал wildfly quickstart мастер ветку, но не могу ее скомпилировать так, как при команде mvn install выдаются подобные ошибки :

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wildfly.quickstarts:quickstart-parent:21.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Main\Desktop\MyTutorials\quickstart-master\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools:pom:21.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-
group has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 102, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-microprofile:pom:21.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has
 elapsed or updates are forced @ line 110, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

`

```
[INFO] --- jaxws-tools-maven-plugin:1.2.3.Final:wsconsume (default) @ jaxws-retail-service ---
[ERROR] "C:\Program" ?? пў?п?вбп ў?гва????? Ё?Ё ў??и???
[ERROR] Є?? ?¤??, ЁбЇ???п???? Їа??а ???? Ё?Ё Ї Є?в?л? д ????.
[INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Quickstart: jaxws-retail 20.0.0.Final:
[INFO]
[INFO] Quickstart: jaxws-retail ........................... SUCCESS [  0.923 s]
[INFO] Quickstart: jaxws-retail - service ................. FAILURE [  0.839 s]
[INFO] Quickstart: jaxws-retail - client .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.911 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-26T14:59:21+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.ws.plugins:jaxws-tools-maven-plugin:1.2.3.Final:wsconsume (default) on project jaxws-retail-service: Error while running wsconsume: Process terminated with code 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109874/discussion-on-question-by-fps-bard---wildfly-quickstart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для корректной работы maven, да и некоторых других утилит, необходимо, чтобы по пути к нему не было пробелов. Такой путь C:\Program Files\java\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin может вызывать ошибки.